# Unable to display JSON in string format when using select/option tags

Tags: angular

I am attempting to retrieve a json array of objects and show the strings in a dropdown and then use the
selected string to post to server. Dropdown is showing items as [object Object]

If I  use | json - however, the post then posts objects...

```
//data returned from rest post call
[{"strtype":"str1"},{"strtype":"str2"},{"strtype":"str3"},{"strtype":"str4"}]

// Strtype.ts
export class Strtype {
    constructor(
        public strtype: string
    ) {}
    setStrtype(doctype) {
        this.strtype = strtype;
    }
}

// app.component.html:
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="strtype">
        String Type
    </label>
    <select id="strtype" class="form-control" 
        [(ngModel)]="document.strtype" name="strtype" #strtype="ngModel">
        <option *ngFor="let strtype of strtypes" [value]="strtype">{{strtype}}</option>
    </select>
</div>


// app.component.ts
strtypes : strtype [];

ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get(this.getstrtypesurl)
    .subscribe((data: strtype[])  => {
        this.strtypes = data
    });
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you call `{{ strtype.strtype }}` ?

Comment: `strtype.strytype`

Answer (score 0):

You should use `strtype.strtype`. Your array is called `strtypes`. Each iteration of the array contains a `strtype` object, and each `strtype` object contains a field `strtype`. If you want the value of the `strtype` field, then you should use :

```
 <option *ngFor="let strtype of strtypes" [value]="strtype.strtype">{{strtype.strtype}}</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're forgetting to get value from `strtype`, use

```
{{strtype.strtype}}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
Use NgOptions instead of looping through

Eg. below

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<select ng-model="selectedName" ng-options="item.label for item in names">
</select>

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.names = [{"label": "Emil"},{"label": "Tobias"}, {"label": "Linus"}];
});
</script>

<p>This example shows how to fill a dropdown list using the ng-options directive.</p>

</body>
</html>
```